# make list of values by getting keys from dictionary and overriding with values from .py file

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to make a list of values passed to variables `var1` and `var2` from `env.py` and use them inside `Generic Suite Setup` keyword without altering the arguments given to `Generic Suite Setup`.

**Setup.robot**

```
*** Keywords ***
Generic Suite Setup 
    [Arguments]    &{options}
    ${keys}=   Get Dictionary Keys     ${options}
    ${new1}=   Convert To List    ${keys}
    Log    ${new1}
```

**env.py**

```
var1='xyz'
var2='pqr'
```

**test.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
    Suite Setup    Generic Suite Setup    var1=abc    var2=abc
```

Comment: So what have you tried? What happens and what would you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to get the keys from argument/s and converting them to a list but cant figure out a way to turn this list of keys to list of values coming from env.py

Comment: Please show the code you have written (only the relevant parts) and show us what the result is and what you would expect it to be.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solve your issue

test.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    Setup.robot
Suite Setup    Generic Suite Setup    var1=abc    var2=abc

*** Test Cases ***
Login
```

Setup.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
*** Keywords ***
Generic Suite Setup 
    [Arguments]    &{options}
    ${keys}=   Get Dictionary Keys     ${options}
    ${Values}=  Get Dictionary Values     ${options}  
    ${new1}=   Convert To List    ${keys}
    ${new2}=   Convert To List    ${Values}
    ${list4}=    Create List    ${var1}    ${var2}

    Log    ${new1}
    Log to console    ${new2}
    Log to console    ${list4}  
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{new1}
    \    Set suite Variable    ${${key}}    ${${key}}
```

env.py

```
var1='xyz'
var2='pqr'
```

output

```
list4= ['xyz','pqr']
```

You now have two separate lists , one is from generic suite setup argument  values and other is from env44.py var1,var2 values

Comment: I cannot use  ${list4}=    Create List    ${var1}    ${var2} in setup.robot because these variable names,values and number of variables are changing with every test script.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is several problems wrapped into one. The first one is that an unknown number of Global Variables are declared. Global variables, due to their nature, should be few and mostly static in nature. This makes them predictable and their presence should be known.

If you're importing variables from an external source, I'd recommend against creating individual Global Variables, but instead use YAML to create a Nested Dictionary/List/Variable. In this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490802/how-to-make-variables-from-import-variables-globally-available/47495342#47495342) I presented an example of a single variable import that is then split into separate global variables. This should provide you with the control over what was imported.

Answer (score 0):

Now `${userlist}` logs as `['xyz', 'pqr']` with following changes in setup.robot

**Setup.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Keywords ***
Generic Suite Setup 
    ${keys}=   Get Dictionary Keys     ${options}
    ${new1}=   Convert To List    ${keys}
    @{userlist}=    Create list
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{new1}
    \    Set suite Variable    ${${key}}    ${${key}}
    \    Append To List    ${userlist}    ${${key}}
    Log    ${userlist}
```