# Import Variables in Suite Setup does not import variables for all the test suite

Tags: python, robotframework

I am kinda new with Robot.
similarly to this [How to make variables from 'Import Variables' globally available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490802/how-to-make-variables-from-import-variables-globally-available)

I am trying to import dynamically variables defined in a python file depending if the tester specified --variable device:A or device:B

Both devices have the same variables but values are different.

My repo looks like this:

```
folder
      |_ __init__.robot
      |_ test.robot
```

I have something like that in the __init__.robot:

```
In __init__.robot:

Suite Setup      Initialize Device

*** Keywords ***    
Initialize Device
    [Documentation]    Initializes the device based on a constant value
    [Arguments]    ${device_type}
    IF   '${device_type}' == 'A'
        Import Variables  projects/A/variables_A.py
    ELSE IF    '${device_type}' == 'B'
        Import Variables  projects/B/variables_B.py
END
```

And in test.robot:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Print device ID
    Log ${device_id}
```

The variable device_id is defined in both variables_X.py files

It works fine for the Setup Suite function, variables are loaded as I expected but as soon as my first test starts, the variables imported are unknown, like out of scope. I thought importing them from the Suite Setup would import them for the whole Test suite as described by robot manual:

> Variables imported with this keyword are set into the test suite scope
> similarly when importing them in the Setting table using the Variables
> setting.

My solution would be to iterate this file and use Set Global Variable/Set Suite Variable but I am curious to know why it does not work as I expected, any ideas?